# What is the Windows Message that indicates a change in the Windows app mode (dark or light)?

Tags: windows, messaging

I am working on a Delphi VCL app that already has the ability to access the user's registry setting to determine if the user has dark mode or light mode set at the time my app opens.

However, the one thing I have not been able to find is a Windows Message that would inform me if a user switched their "default app mode" (light or dark) while my application is running.

**Does the Windows API provide a Windows Message indicating a change in the default app mode?**

Comment: Ought to be WM_SETTINGCHANGE, check with Spy++.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about spy++. That is very helpful. WM_SETTINGCHANGE was among the messages, but there were others. I'm going to play with those and see if there is one that is specific to the color.

Comment: In using Spy++, I think the more specific flag that I would care about may be WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED. The "WM_SETTINGCHANGE" flag appears to trigger at other times in addition to when I change the app mode.